# C++ File/Directory stat with variable

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to check if directory exist. I want to make it more reliable and I'm trying to use stat with predefined variable which check user name, but all the time I'm getting an error.

Here's userdir string output : /home/root/test

```
    string userdir="/home/"+user+"/test";

  struct stat st ;
  if(stat(userdir, &st) == 0)
    printf( "test directory exist\n" );
  else
    printf("test directory don't exist\n");
```

Comment: Generally it's far easier for people to answer your questions if you include an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `string` is `std::string` then you need to call `stat(userdir.c_str(), &st)` - `stat` takes a C style string, not a C++ one.

Minimal example:

```
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  const std::string dir="/tmp";
  struct stat st;

  return stat(dir, &st); // Error

  return stat(dir.c_str(), &st); // Correct
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`stat()` takes a `const char *`, not an `std::string`:

```
if (stat(userdir.c_str(), &st) == 0)
//               ^^^^^^^
```